# What are the procedure to install the drivers for the ati radeon mobility x2300?

Tags: radeon

I recently decided to scrap my windows partition for Ubuntu 13.04 when I found out steam is available for linux. I just cant seem to play any games on it because I can't find how to install the right graphics driver. I have an ATI Radeon mobility x2300. It is an HP compaq 6910p notebook.

Any info on the subject would be awesome.

Comment: If that is a similar card to my X1300 you cannot get any drivers from AMD any more.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the AMD support website and found out that they don't offer any drivers anymore. Nether for Linux nor Windows nor Mac OS. It seems you have to live with the open source/default driver.

You could have a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) open source driver. It says the 3D doesn't work as fast as with the `fglrx` driver but you could try...